# South - Migrate PyPI package

Tags: django, git, virtualenv, pip, django-south

When I install a new package let's say

```
(myenv) $ pip install django-avatar
```

After having added it in my project

```python
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    #...
    'avatar',
)
```

As I'm using South, I'll want to add the migration to my project

```
(myenv) $ python manage.py schemamigration avatar --initial
```

> + Added model avatar.Avatar
>   Created 0001_initial.py. You can now apply this migration with: ./manage.py migrate avatar

Now git tells me that nothing have changed in my project

Where is this migration file ?
How can I deploy it ?

Comment: http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/whataremigrations.html http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html#part-1-the-basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you run that command, followed by `./manage.py migrate avatar` the migration will be written to `/migrations/0001_initial.py` and to a table in your DB. For MySQL it's `south_migrationhistory`.

As for deployment, my preference is to run the south `schemamigration` and `migrate` commands on production. And to keep the local `migrations` directory off production.

I do this because I usually perform more migrations in development, and (until 1.7, anyway) that directory can get rather unwieldy.

Comment: Thanks for this clear explanation, as my migration files usually go on each app folder, I though it were doing the same for virtualenv apps. +1 for the production tip

Comment: By the way, migrations only on production, doesn't this prevent you from choosing any version of your project you may wish to install ?

Comment: Actually I don't see the migration coming in `migrations/` see my updated question

Comment: You can't really use the migrations files to revert. The problem is that your models needs to match your DB. That's why have /migrations in .gitignore.

Comment: To roll back, you need to roll back your models, then apply `schemamigration`.

Comment: I'd not gitignore migrations because I use them to replicate the migrations in production (or other environments) as soon as I'm sure they are correct in dev

Comment: Yes, but that's not really what South is about. If you revert using migrations, then your models will be wrong and you'll have to correct them. Better to just use git to keep the code correct, and then migrate.